# Contents of Content Control gone on tab switch

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am using mvvm. I am loading a usercontrol that contains a content control on two different tabs like so:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="View">
        <StackPanel>
            <Info:UserData/><!--UserData Control-->
            <Button Content="View Entries" Command="{Binding BeginView}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem >
    <TabItem Header="Edit">
        <StackPanel>
            <Info:UserData/><!--UserData Control-->
            <Button Content="Edit Entries" Command="{Binding BeginEdit}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem >
</TabControl>
```

The User Control looks like:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding UserTypeInfo}"/>
    <Info:UserDetailsArea Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

When the tab first loads the content of the ContentControl is set to an image. Depending on some actions the content may change to a datatable, video, etc. This part works fine.

When it loads the default tab is the first one. If I click on the second tab, you should see the same thing - with a different button, this works. But if I go back to the first tab the Content control is empty.

What do I need to do so that both tabs display the image?

The value bound to from the viewmodel as requested:

```
private object userTypeInfo
/// <summary>
/// User Specific data
/// </summary>
public object UserTypeInfo
{
    get
    {
        return userTypeInfo;
    }
    private set
    {
        UuserTypeInfo= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("UserTypeInfo");
    }
}
```

Edit:
The following is a simplified example that I believe shows the same problem:

XAML code for window:

```
<Window x:Class="dualCC.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="One">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Button Content="One" />
                    <ContentControl Name="CCone"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Two">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Button Content="Two" />
                    <ContentControl Name="CCtwo"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind (you'll need to fix the path to an image):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace dualCC
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(@"C:\Image.jpg");
            BitmapImage temp = new BitmapImage(uri);
            Image CurrentImage = new Image();
            CurrentImage.Source = temp;

            CCone.Content = CurrentImage;
            CCtwo.Content = CurrentImage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your VM please. Can you also provide a simple example that I can look at?

Comment: Shared example with reproducable issue would be good

Answer (score 2):

This isn't MVVM. In MVVM you never manipulate GUI elements directly in code-behind like this.

To answer your question, the problem is that you're creating an `Image`, which is actually a child control, and setting it as the content of two separate controls. Controls can only have one parent. Create separate Images instead and set the BitmapImage as the source for each:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(@"C:\Image.jpg");
        BitmapImage temp = new BitmapImage(uri);

        CCone.Content = new Image { Source = temp };
        CCtwo.Content = new Image { Source = temp };
    }
```

Or better yet use proper MVVM and do it with data binding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought this was the case. Please note that about halfway down the question I posted a simplified example. In my actual code I am using MVVM (as seen in the first half of the description). But I believe the end result is the same, since there are 2 views, using the same viewmodel, the same image is in both view, and the parent switches to the second one.